# Adding checkboxes to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to add custom checkboxes to highcharts?

Currently im using a custom button to show/hide a plotband:

```
exporting : {
    buttons : {
        customButton : {
            onclick : function() {
                //do stuff
            },
            text : 'Show plotband',
            enabled : true
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously for something like show/hide functionality, a checkbox makes more sense than a button. Is there a way to use exporting as i've done above, to add a checkbox?

Many thanks.

Comment: Highcharts draws the exporting buttons using SVG.  Why don't you just create an HTML checkbox and position it on top of the chart?

Comment: Yes, that is what i've been doing up until now. However I was hoping there was a way to do it through highcharts (to embed the checkbox), so I didn't have to worry about positioning of items on the page in relation to the chart,...it would actually be a part of the chart. Im not sure if it's even possible. Many thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately its not possible, but you can add html buttons and use position: absolute / define top/left parameters (to set coordinates). Catch event by jquery and call any action on the chart

Comment: Ok thanks. I had a feeling I would have to do that I just wanted to make sure.